# Remove knob from this door handle (F605-245)

Tags: interior, hardware, doorknob

I have, what I believe, is a Schlage interior door handle with a privacy lock (you engage a push pin with a narrow wire or whatever fits to disengage the lock from outside the door).
The push button knob end is marked F605-238 and the knob I’m concerned with is marked F605-245.

The issue I’m having is I’m trying to remove the knob from the handle assembly, but the knob actually looks crimped on (I’m not seeing any release mechanism to allow the knob to slide off) and I am not seeing an obvious way to get behind the rosette.

I’ve had no luck finding this particular handle anywhere online so I’m hoping someone here has come up against this before and can give me a few pointers before I ruin this thing.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm thinking there's a bit you can access in the open side of the single divot with a pointy tool, but don't recall the details. A "less obvious/easy" spring catch as it were. Possibly with a "and then twist and slide" action. But vague and possibly not this exact one.

Comment: Why do you want to remove the knob, what is the problem you’re trying to solve?  it may not be designed to be removed.

Comment: @AlaskaMan That hole is the perfect size for Lego pieces to fit into, and if possible, I’d love to extract them so it stops sounding like a maraca every time I twist the handle.